# Why ion auth library use custom where() instead of using the native where() CI provided

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

```
    public function groups()
{
    $this->trigger_events('groups');

    // run each where that was passed
    if (isset($this->_ion_where) && !empty($this->_ion_where))
    {
        foreach ($this->_ion_where as $where)
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $this->_ion_where = array();
    }

    if (isset($this->_ion_limit) && isset($this->_ion_offset))
    {
        $this->db->limit($this->_ion_limit, $this->_ion_offset);

        $this->_ion_limit  = NULL;
        $this->_ion_offset = NULL;
    }
    else if (isset($this->_ion_limit))
    {
        $this->db->limit($this->_ion_limit);

        $this->_ion_limit  = NULL;
    }

    // set the order
    if (isset($this->_ion_order_by) && isset($this->_ion_order))
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_ion_order_by, $this->_ion_order);
    }

    $this->response = $this->db->get($this->tables['groups']);

    return $this;
}
```

It seems nonsense to me as you can see from the groups() function above, why use the custom _ion_limit, _ion_offset, _ion_where when CI has already give you the choice to write native where()->limit()->get(), keep its own private _ion_limit, _ion_offset, _ion_where private property does anything good to the workflow? DO I miss some part here or is there some design pattern involved here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the main reason is to implement event hook functionality. All the "duplicate" db functions make a call to `$this->trigger_events()` which in turn calls any function provided to `set_hook()`.

I have a really vague recollection of noticing some other decent reason. But that was back quite a long time and I cannot remember what it was.

Comment: Maybe true, it seems like it will be more flexible to fabricated the sql clause